# Changing cloudinary file default url per uploader

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cloudinary

I have a `Rails 4` app with `Ruby 2.2.0`.

I am building an app for where I need to store quite a bit of images. Currently the app exists and is managing their images on a local server, however we want to change that.

The app is currently deployed on Heroku and we want to use the `Cloudinary` service to upload(using `carrierwave`) new images as well as to store the already existing ones.

The issue comes from the fact that I can't seem to be able to adopt the current folder structure that the platform is using. To start with I uploaded all my files via the Media manager in cloudinary dashboard. I created two folders `header` and `logo`. In this case I will refer to the `header` folder as example.

```
class BannerUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include Cloudinary::CarrierWave

  def store_dir
    "uploads/header/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
end
```

The model:

```
class CompanyImage < ActiveRecord::Base

  mount_uploader :file_name, BannerUploader

  belongs_to :company
end
```

And last but not least, here is my view:

```
<%
  work_advantages = company.presentation.work_advantages
  banner = company.company_images.where(header: true).first
%>
<%= link_to company do %>
  <div class="card company-presentation-card card-hover">
    <div class="card-container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="cover-image">
          </div>
          <h3><%= company.name %></h3>
          <% company.company_sectors.each do |s| %>
            <span class="h4-alt1 company-sector"><%= s.sector.name %></span>
          <% end %>
          <p><%= truncate(company.presentation.work_advantages, :length => 250) %> <span class="text-muted">(lees meer)</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>

<script>
  //Set dynamic background image for the cover-image <div>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.company-presentation-card').find('.cover-image').css('background-image', 'url("<%= banner.file_name %>")')
  });
</script>
```

Currently, the url that is being delivered in the following: `http://res.cloudinary.com/hxwmb9swy/image/upload/5a444a7c191e8c98999f6d0c2d3afaf9_Arendsen_Machinefabriek.jpg` however I need to have the `header`(the folder I created in Cloudinary) folder in there so the url should actually look like this: `http://res.cloudinary.com/hxwmb9swy/image/upload/header/5a444a7c191e8c98999f6d0c2d3afaf9_Arendsen_Machinefabriek.jpg`

Of course in the case of the logo, its exactly the same however instead of `header` it should say `logo`. This will also apply to other models. So my question is how can I manage this in a way, so that I can specify this folder per `uploader`? Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

The `header` or `logo` should be included in the image's public ID. So if you do a server-side upload, you can override the `public_id` method in your uploader to include the folder. For example, the following sets the public ID as the `header` folder with the original image's filename (without the extension, as it should):

```
def public_id
    basename = File.basename(original_filename, File.extname(original_filename))
    "header/#{basename}"
end
```

If you do a client-side upload, with Cloudinary's `cl_image_upload` for example, you can do something like:

```
<%= f.cl_image_upload(:image, :folder => "header") %>
```

For the 2nd case, there's no need to change anything in your Uploader.

Comment: That looks intriguing. I will test as soon as I can, probably tomorrow and let you know if it solved my issue.

Comment: hey, issue still seems to persist. If I understood right, i should modify the Public_id within the uploaders corresponding to either header or logo? I already tried to put it in the header uploader, but the links i receive when calling the file_name still returns an url without the folder.

Comment: P.S. The overwrite of `public_id` actually works. Playing a bit in the rails console this is what I managed to find: `:003 > c.company_images.first.file_name.public_id CompanyImage Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "company_images".* FROM "company_images" WHERE "company_images"."company_id" = $1  ORDER BY "company_images"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["company_id", 23]]
 => "header/3559dff80c43e061d517870d3e997bf1_13b9719fdda733aa92e436c36542bd34_Rensa_VerwVentil_rgb"`

Comment: Couple of questions. 1-So you upload the images from the server-side, right? 2-What would you like the rest of the public ID (after the header or logo folder)? Is it a public ID you set, original file name, or some kind of a random string?

Comment: 1 - For now, I don't want to upload server side. I have uploaded my files via the media manager as its an already existing platform which we are rebuilding and migrating the data => all current users need to find their pictures. Once the platform is up and running, the users will of course be able to upload images. 2- at the moment the file names are random strings. I am not really sure exactly how they were generated, as the old platform works

Comment: Sorry for my delay. Media manager - you mean Cloudinary's Media library? When your platform is up and running, you should be able to use the client-side code I shared previously to store the uploaded images in the corresponding folder. This way, Cloudinary would take care of generating a random characters public ID

Answer (score 0):

Create custom name folder Cloudinary with CarrierWave

```
include Cloudinary::CarrierWave

def public_id
 return "my_folder/" + Cloudinary::Utils.random_public_id;
end
```